# unexpected output while trying to convert html to pdf in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pdf-generation

here is my view to which converts html to django

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer))
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id, *args, **kwargs):
# def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):

    queryset=D.objects.all()
    # serializer=
    order = get_object_or_404(queryset, id=order_id)
    price=order.price
    discount=order.discount
    total=price-discount
    template=get_template('bill/bill.html')
    data={
    'order': order,'total':total
    }
    html = render_to_pdf('bill/bill.html',
    data)
    return HttpResponse(html, content_type='application/pdf')
```

and this is the code for render_to_pdf

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

and my urls.py

```
re_path(r'^bill/(?P<order_id>\d+)/pdf/$',
    admin_order_pdf,
 name='admin_order_pdf'),
```

and my html template

```
<html>
<body>
 <h1>My Shop</h1>
 <p>
   {% for ord in order %}
   <li>{{ ord.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
```

but whenever i tried to access the url i could load the pdf but there isnt any content in that particular pdf file except a single word "profiles" i dont even know where that word came from

Comment: Why are you using an API view for this? Why have you decorated it with a JSONRenderer? This should be a standard Django view that returns a PDF.

Comment: And also you're wrapping the returned HttpResponse from `render_to_pdf` in another HttpResponse, you definitely don't want to do that.

Comment: i removed those decorators and tried running but its of no use  and regarding  the  Http Response can you just give me an idea what i need to do because  i have just followed everything as in one of the turorial

Comment: You should return `html` directly from your view rather than wrapping it in another HttpResponse.

Comment: should i remove the last three lines from render_to_pdf  code ??

Comment: No, something needs to create the HttpResponse.

Comment: then what should i do ??

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer. Return `html` directly from `admin_order_pdf` without wrapping it in an HttpResponse.